# Manipulate list using index calculation

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, concatenation

I have a list of strings:

```
String_list = ['Please','attach','all','the','key','content','for','each','topic']
```

and a list of index

```
index = [1,4]
```

The matched items with 2 words before and 2 after combined will be marked as “key
content”. Is there a way to return a concat string of the key content?

For this specific example, the output should be:

```
'Please attach all the key content for'
```

For the index 1: the 'key content' would be item with index 0,1,2,3 (since 'attach' is the second element in the list), and for index 4, the matching index would be 2,3,4,5,6. When combined, the key content would be the above output.

Comment: Can u rephrase your question?

Comment: `if index[0] != 0 and index[1] != len(String_list):
    print(' '.join(String_list[index[0]-1:index[1]+3]))

else:
    print(' '.join(String_list[index[0]:index[1]]))`  is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String_list = ['Please', 'attach', 'all', 'the', 'key', 'content', 'for', 'each', 'topic']
    index = [1,4]
    
    # get -2, +2 range string indices for each index
    str_index = [i for idx in index for i in range(idx-2, idx+3) if i >= 0 and i < len(String_list)]  
    
    # remove duplicates
    str_index = list(set(str_index))

    # get string at indices
    target_strings = [String_list[idx] for idx in str_index]

    # format into desired output and print
    print(' '.join(target_strings))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Pythonic way:

Code:

```
String_list = ['Please','attach','all','the','key','content','for','each','topic']
index = [1,4]
list_ind = []
[list_ind.extend([i-2,i-1,i,i+1,i+2]) for i in index]
res_str = ' '.join([String_list[i] for i in sorted(set(list_ind)) if i >= 0])
print(res_str)
```

Output:

```
Please attach all the key content for
```